# why using Myarray.size() returns error : " int object is not callable " but Myarray.size is Ok?

Tags: python, function, numpy, size

I have a wierd Problem which is when i use .size() i get error but using .size is ok.
look at below :

```py
a = np.zeros([5,5])
a.size # returns 25
a.size() # returns error : "int obj is not callable "
a.shape # returns (5,5)
```

The problem is that i must have .size() working because I'm defining an embedding layer "emb_layer" in Pytorch and trying to load its state using a matrix called " weights_matrix " :

```
emb_layer.load_state_dict({'weight': weights_matrix})
```

and it seems .load_state_dict() uses .size() inside !

```py
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _load_from_state_dict(self, state_dict, prefix, local_metadata, strict, missing_keys, unexpected_keys, error_msgs)
    709                                       'whose dimensions in the model are {} and '
    710                                       'whose dimensions in the checkpoint are {}.'
--> 711                                       .format(key, param.size(), input_param.size()))
    712             elif strict:
    713                 missing_keys.append(key)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

`ndarray.size` is an [attribute](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html), not a function. You can't call it because it is actually just a number:

> `ndarray.size`
>
> Number of elements in the array.
>
> Equal to `np.prod(a.shape)`, i.e., the product of the array’s dimensions.
>
> Notes
>
> `a.size` returns a standard arbitrary precision Python integer. This may not be the case with other methods of obtaining the same value (like the suggested `np.prod(a.shape)`, which returns an instance of `np.int_`), and may be relevant if the value is used further in calculations that may overflow a fixed size integer type.

Comment: I've edited My Question , what about .load_state_dict() which needs .size() inside ?

Comment: Looks like a PyTorch models use function `size()` inside. It is not a `ndarray.size`, it is another function with the same name.

Comment: it shows error Because param.size is " int " , so it shows the same error for param.size() !!

Comment: Solved The problem using: nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(torch.FloatTensor(weights_matrix)).

Comment: Whether something is a function or not is unrelated to whether it is an attribute of something or not. In this particular case _"...it is actually just a number..."_ is especially misleading since `np.ndarray.size` is actually a `getset_descriptor`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, I normally write that "`arr.shape` is a tuple", even though it's more accurate to say "`arr.shape` returns a tuple".  I have no idea what the underlying `shape` method is called.

Comment: @hpaulj I'd argue the distinction isn't merely philosophical, since unlike a "simple" number or tuple attribute, `size` and `shape` disallow or consistency check and normalize assignment. I'd assume that's why they are implemented as descriptors in the first place. Btw. you can check for descriptorness through the presence or absence of a `__get__` member. You just need to make sure you get at it before python does: `arr.size.__get__` will not work but `arr.__class__.size.__get__` will.

Comment: @hpaulj Such `property` like descriptors are essentially syntactic sugar for `get*/set*` pairs, so in a sense `size` and `shape` are methods in all but syntax.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, `ndarray` is mostly defined in C code.  Looks like most of the getter/setter stuff is in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/getset.c.  It links `size` to `array_size_get` which calls `PyArray_SIZE(self)`, which in turn is defined as `PyArray_MultiplyList(PyArray_DIMS(m), PyArray_NDIM(m))`, the product of the `shape`.  `shape` also uses `PyArray_NDIM` but converts it to a tuple.